# How to add recurrent dropout to CuDNNGRU or CuDNNLSTM in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

One can apply recurrent dropout onto basic LSTM or GRU layers in Keras by passing its value as a parameter of the layer.

CuDNNLSTM and CuDNNGRU are LSTM and GRU layers that are compatible with CUDA. The main advantage is that they are 10 times faster during training. However they lack some of the beauty of the LSTM or GRU layers in Keras, namely the possibility to pass dropout or recurrent dropout values.

While we can add Dropout layers directly in the model, it seems we cannot do that with Recurrent Dropout.

My question is then the following : **How to add recurrent dropout to CuDNNGRU or CuDNNLSTM in Keras ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think we can have it as it is not even supported in the low level (i.e. cuDNN). [From François Chollet](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8935#issuecomment-365733367) creator of Keras:

> Recurrent dropout is not implemented in cuDNN RNN ops. At the cuDNN level. So we can't have it in Keras.
>
> The dropout option in the cuDNN API is not recurrent dropout (unlike what is in Keras), so it is basically useless (regular dropout doesn't work with RNNs).
>
> Actually using such dropout in a stacked RNN will wreck training.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I hope they implement it soon !

Answer (score 3):

You can use kernel_regularizer and recurrent_regularizer for prevent overfitting, i am using L2 regularizers and i am having good results.

Comment: This may be a bit late, but could you expand on your answer a little bit ? I also use regularizers to prevent overfitting -and it works- but despite my best efforts this is always at the cost of a great drop in accuracy (more than 15%). I would very much appreciate more details if you step by here.

Comment: When using regularization, a drop in accuracy necessarily occurs, since regularization fines data. But you get more accuracy on test data. You can try different types of regularization. L1, L2, L1_L2